# Python: Convert several(multiple) docx files to pdf from a particular folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, converters

I want to convert multiple/several files from .docx to PDF using Python. I made a code, but is not working. I am beginner. Can anyone help me a little bit?

```
import re
import os
from pathlib import Path
import sys
from docx2pdf import convert

# The location where the files are located
input_path = r'c:\Folder7\input'
# The location where we will write the PDF files
output_path = r'c:\Folder7\output'
# Creeaza structura de foldere daca nu exista
os.makedirs(output_path, exist_ok=True)

# Verifica existenta folder-ului
directory_path = Path(input_path)
if directory_path.exists() and directory_path.is_dir():
    print(directory_path, "exists")
else:
    print(directory_path, "is invalid")
    sys.exit(1)

for file_path in directory_path.glob("*"):
    # file_path is a Path object

    print("Procesez fisierul:", file_path)
    document = Document()
    # file_path.name is the name of the file as str without the Path
    document.add_heading(file_path.name, 0)

    file_content = file_path.read_text(encoding='UTF-8')
    document.add_paragraph(file_content)

    # build the new path where we store the files
    output_file_path = os.path.join(output_path, file_path.name + ".pdf")

    document.save(output_file_path)
    print("Am convertit urmatorul fisier:", file_path, "in: ", output_file_path)
```

**I get this error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Convert docx to pdf.py", line 26, in <module>
    document = Document()
NameError: name 'Document' is not defined
```

I am beginner. Can anyone help me to make this code working ?

Comment: You didn't import `Document` from anywhere that I can see. Which package is supposed to expose it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This will work**

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
import sys
from docx2pdf import convert


# The location where the files are located
input_path = r'c:\Folder7\input'
# The location where we will write the PDF files
output_path = r'c:\Folder7\output'
# Creeaza structura de foldere daca nu exista
os.makedirs(output_path, exist_ok=True)

# Verifica existenta folder-ului
directory_path = Path(input_path)
if directory_path.exists() and directory_path.is_dir():
    print(directory_path, "exists")
else:
    print(directory_path, "is invalid")
    sys.exit(1)

for file_path in directory_path.glob("*"):
    print("Procesez fisierul:", file_path)

    # build the new path where we store the files
    output_file_path = os.path.join(output_path, file_path.stem + ".pdf")
    input_file_path = os.path.join(input_path, file_path.name)

    convert(input_file_path, output_file_path)

    print("Am convertit urmatorul fisier:", file_path, "in: ", output_file_path)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should import Document first. Right now the message is saying that there is no object called Documents in your « toolkit » you can’t use it when you don’t have it. Take a look to your imports you can maybe try to import Document from Docx2pdf as you did for convert.

Update : This can ´maybe help you
https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/